# Merits vs. Good Karma vs. Acting out of Anger

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, dharma, sin

Is Merit different from Good Karma?

Is repeatedly doing a meritorious act called Good Karma?

Somewhere I read that one drop of acid ruins a good and tasty soup. In the same way once person a got very angry, it wiped out all the merits done by him.

So does anger really wipe out all the merits done by the person?

If a person gets angry, then does all his charity acts, or only all kinds of meritorious acts get wiped out?

Aren't there separate accounts (or baskets) for good and bad deeds? E.g., if a man does charity and gets angry upon someone then don't both these fructify separately?

Comment: Yeah you're right. it all depends on the type of actions performed. Nobody can pin point that this is how it will happen. It depends on so many factors. Theoretically, every karma has its own effect. However in practice, karma can appear to get intermingled with other karma and it may appear to have a 'nullification effect'. The reason? The Mind is the reason. Mind is cause of all bondage as well as liberation according to Saints. Run after the mind and you will never catch it, (like a mirage in the desert). However if you run after God, you will eventually overcome the Mind. Good luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically there are two types of Merit Karma.

#### 1) Done for getting Punya-Karma.

*Good work done with an intention of getting good results of that deed. A person may do good work with a view of getting reward either from God, or from other circumstances or in next life. Such Karma are called **Punya Karma**. Doing punya karma is good but these karma gets nullified after getting Reward of that Karma.*

#### 2) Done as Dharmic activity:

*Good work done without having intention of getting some good from that. This type of Karma through KarmaYoga is the best Karma as it do not lead to attachment and this type of Karma lead a person towards the door of Mokshya.*

Being angry doesn't wipe merits of events when the events are not interconnected...But If you become angry in the events related to that Karma then only it deteriorates that Karma.

> Even Lord Rama who is the highest standard of Dharma (Maryada Purushottama) was angry in certain events like... anger with Sea-God, anger with Sugriv etc...

Comment: That explains a lot :)