# Can sex boost one's Sadhana?

Tags: sex, kama

In [this video](https://youtu.be/_B70u68rfeU) the speaker Rohit Arya says at 1:21 minutes that sex if used 'correctly' can boost one's Sadhana

1. Is there any scriptural evidence to support his statement?
2. What can possibly be the correct way of performing sexual intercourse?

Comment: In sadhana you can't have sex. Because sadhana means you have to leave materialistic pleasure, and that includes sex.

Comment: Nothing like that today can be done, expect its prevention (ciliblicy) when prescribed or as required or possibly mandatory. For tantric perspective see these: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18999/21353
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19013/21353

Comment: They mean sexual energy. When that energy is lifted upwards in sushumna its sadhana.

Comment: What does "boosting Sadhana" mean?

Comment: no. it cannot. exact opposite

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because youtube opinions should be addressed and answered by the authors and purveyors of the youtube videos.This forum is not meant to answer opinions expressed on youtube.

Comment: Read Patanjali's Yoga Sutras, specifically what constitutes the first step, Yama.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda That's exactly what has been asked in the question; I want to know what is written in our scriptures so if you could elaborate more than just "Read Patanjali's Yoga Sutras" it will be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any scriptural evidence to support his statement?

Yes it has a scriptural support

> Her lap is the sacrificial altar, her hair the sacrificial grass, her skin within the organ the lighted fire; the two labia of the vulva are the two stones of the soma-press.
>
> He who, knowing this, practices sexual intercourse wins as great a world as is won through the Vājapeya sacrifice; he acquires for himself the fruit of the good deeds of the woman. But he who, without knowing this, practices sexual intercourse turns over to the woman his own good deeds.(Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 6:4:3-4)

---

<sup>I will update my answer soon</sup>