# What exactly is Vamachara?

Tags: scripture, terminology, vamachara

For any great verses or naamas in scriptures, there can be different kinds of interpretations. Dharmic, vedic etc., are the types of interpretations.

I heard that there can be another type of interpretation, which is called vamacharic interpretation.

What exactly is vamachara? What are the scriptures related to vamachara? Does it belong to nirukta?

Comment: "Does it belong to nirukta?" - Lol no, nirukta is etymology of sanskrit words. Vamachara means "left hand path", and it's about sex, meat, alcohol, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Oh! I recently heard about it. So, having no idea, asked about it.

Comment: Don’t know but I think vamachara means asuric form of worship where you’d use your left hand and do parikrama anti-clockwise (everything opposite to devata worship). There’s some other vamachara of tantras which is different from asuric form of worship.

Comment: vama means beautiful, it also means left.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Dakṣiṇācāra and Vamachara Tantrism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/what-is-the-difference-between-dak%e1%b9%a3i%e1%b9%87%c4%81c%c4%81ra-and-vamachara-tantrism)