# In search of Tantra Practitioners

Tags: tantra

Are there any authentic Tantra practitioners in North America? The ones I've found all seem to be "Neo-tantra".

Comment: The so-called "Tantra" that is being taught to you in those countries and they are teaching you various sexual contortions in name of "Tantra" and making you imagine a so-called energy circle moving in your brain and spine and et cetera things they make you do in name of "Tantra", is all wrong. If you also mean by "Tantra" a man and a woman teaching you various sexual body contortions. Then, you must be acknowledged that it is actually not tantra. You are being misguided in name of Tantra.

Comment: This is what I meant. Tantra is so confused with "sex" in the West that a new word needs to be invented to describe it. At least in English. I'd hoped for something authentic in North America, but it seems one must travel to the cremation grounds in India to find it.

Comment: read answer to this question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12249/does-advaita-accept-vamchara-followers/12276#12276

Comment: Thank you. Good commentary on the Tantras. Too bad the comments on the thread turn into arguments.

Comment: @Rummah there is agama room.for Tantra discussion. There you may get some link for people in your place.